# how to input values into ArrayList alphabetically

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm given the task of adding a value into an ArrayList alphabetically (by lastname first, and firstname if lastnames are the same),I'm not allowed to sort the ArrayList once all the inputs are given. What I am suppose to do is determine the location of where the value should be each time an input is given and place it there. Example values: Inputs are {John Doe, Bryan Sully, Harry Ache, Ali Doe, Bry Dyre} , Output should be {Harry Ache, Ali Doe, John Doe, Bry Dyre, Bryan Sully}. However, in cases where there are two of the same last names, what will occur is {Harry Ache, Ali Doe, Bry Dyre, John Doe, Bryan Sully}, why?

```java
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

public void addPerson(Person p){
    if(list.size() == 0){
      list.add(p);
    } else{
      for(Person pp: list){
        int getIndex = list.indexOf(pp);
        int lOrder = p.getLastName().compareTo(pp.getLastName());
        if(lOrder > 0){
          list.add(getIndex + 1, p);
          break;
        } else if(lOrder == 0){
          int fOrder = p.getFirstName().compareTo(pp.getFirstName());
          if(fOrder > 0){
            list.add(getIndex, p);
            break;
          } else {
            list.add(getIndex + 1, p);
            break;
          }
        } else {
          list.add(getIndex, p);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Exactly *what* “certain circumstances” cause the problem? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, see [*insertion sort*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: I recommend you to implement the Comparable interface in your Person class in order to implement your own comparison algorithm (firstname then lastname). This will allow you to compare Person objects directly and will make your code easier to read.

Comment: @Bohemian as now stated in the question, in cases where there are two of the same last names, the last names will not be together but rather there is a split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue with your code is that you are making an insertion after a single iteration of your loop, inserting `Person` p only in comparison to the first `Person` in the list.

Here is an improved implementation:

```
public void addPerson(Person person) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(p);
    } else {
        // the position where you will insert the Person;
        // default value is list.size(), so it can be added to the end
        int position = list.size();

        Person p;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            p = list.get(i);

            // if the comparison result is > 0, you found the first Person
            // in the list that comes alphabetically after;
            // Insert person before it, at position i
            if (compare(p, person) > 0) {
                position = i;
                break; // only break now that you've found the insert position
            }
        }
        list.add(person, position);
    }
}

/**
 * @return 0 if both Persons p1 & p2 have the same names, 
 *         a positive number if p1 is lexicographically greater than p2, 
 *         or a negative number if p1 is lexicographically less than p2 
 */
private int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    int result = p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
    if (result == 0) {
        result = p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
    }
    return result;
}
```

As others suggested, implementing the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in `Person` if possible can also help create a cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Few improvements.

- You are better off if you can iterate the list using the index like 
  `for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)`
- You need not have to check for `lastName` and `firstName` separately. You can just compare both of them together `(p.lastName + p.firstName).compareTo(pp.lastName + pp.firstName)` and act upon the result. As you already have the index of the current element,  you just have to check if you just insert the new item on the same index or not.

Here is a sample implementation

```
static void addPerson(Person person) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
        var existingPerson = sortedList.get(i);
        var compareResult = compare(existingPerson, person);
        if (compareResult > 0) {
            sortedList.add(i, person);
            return;
        }
    }
    sortedList.add(person);
}

static int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return (p1.lastName + p1.firstName).compareTo(p2.lastName + p2.firstName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your algorithm, is that you always looking at the first person in the target list, and making decisions solely on that person, notice how all your "branches" have a break statement at the end?

I understand your "reason" for adding all those break statements, those make sure the new person always gets inserted into the list, when it doesn't match, the same reason why your first check if the list is empty.

To properly implement an "insertion sort" system, you actually need to loop over all the indexes of your list.

An simple "insertion sort" algorithm looks like this:

1. Loop over the target list
2. Check if existing entry is "bigger" than the newly person
3. If the existing entry is bigger, we need to move that entry (all all remaining entries) up  1 spot, insert out entry, and *abort*
4. If we are done looping, and we didn't abort in the above steps, insert our entry at the end of the list.

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();

public void addPerson(Person p){
    // Loop
    int size = list.size();
    for(int getIndex = 0; getIndex < size; getIndex++){
        Person pp = list.get(getIndex);
        // Compare
        int compare = p.getLastName().compareTo(pp.getLastName());
        if (compare > 0) {
            continue;
        } else if(compare == 0) {
            if (p.getFirstName().compareTo(pp.getFirstName()) > 0) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        // Add in existing slot
        list.add(getIndex, p);
        return;
    }
    // Add at the end
    list.add(p);
}
```

One hard part of this, is the fact that we have to compare on 2 things for a single person, this makes the compare logic way harder than it needs to be. This can be solved by factoring this part out to a "helper" comparator that does this logic merging for us:

```
Comparator<Person> compare = Comparator
    .comparing(Person::getLastName)
    .thenComparing(Person::getFirstName);

// Then, inside the above loop:
        ...
        // Compare
        if (compare.compare(p, pp) > 0) {
            continue;
        }
        ...
```